# php array unset not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of records I want to create a separate array of skills and want to remove duplicate values, unset not providing desired result somehow, I am not able to find out what's wrong. For example I have record (a) in first skills array at index 0 and I have same record in last skills array at index 1 , I just want to remove any duplicate records but unset removing other records also.

```
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0;

$data = array();


$all_data = array ( 0 => array ( "fname" => "Ann",  "skills" => array ( 0 => "a", 1 => "b" )),
1 => array ( "fname" => "Bxx",  "skills" => array ( 0 => "c", 1 => "d" )),
2 => array ( "fname" => "Sdd",  "skills" => array ( 0 => "e", 1 => "a" ))
);


while( $x < count($all_data)){

    while($y < count($all_data[$x]['skills'])){

        $data[$x] = $all_data[$x]['skills'];

        if (in_array($data[$x][$y], $data[$x])){
            unset($data[$x][$y]);
        }

        $y++;
    }

    $y = 0;


    $x++;
}
```

The result I am getting is this

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => e
        [1] => a
    )
```

)

I am expecting

```
Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => e
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$keys=[];
foreach ($all_data as $index1 => $item) {
    if (!isset($item['skills'])) continue;
    foreach ($item['skills'] as $index2 => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, $keys)) {
            $data[$index1][] = $value ;
            $keys[] = $value ;
        }
    }
}
unset($keys);

print_r($data);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

Comment: ok please can you explain this one            if (!isset($item['skills'])) continue;

Comment: @NickTaylor It is a just a test to avoid warnings about using `$item['skills']`. But it could not be yours purpose if you always have a `skills` index.

Comment: hmmm ok gr8. Thank you dear.